# Confidence interval for the 95th percentile of the normal distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, fisher-information

Let $X_1, .., X_n \sim Normal(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

Let $\tau$ be the 95th percentile of this distribution. Thus,

$P(X_i < \tau) = 0.95$.

What is the $1 - \alpha$ confidence interval for $\tau$?

I know how to get the maximum likelihood estimator for $\tau$; I would invoke the equivariance principle and plug in the MLEs for $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

$\hat{\tau} = \bar{X} + S \Phi^{-1}(0.95)$.

However, I'm struggling to estimate the standard error for it.  It likely involves Fisher's information matrix, but I'm stuck at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For normal distribution, $\bar X$ and $S$ are independent. So 
$$\mathrm{Var}(\hat \tau) = \mathrm{Var}(\bar X) +\mathrm{Var}(S \Phi^{-1}(0.95)) = \frac {\sigma^2}n + (\Phi^{-1}(0.95))^2 \mathrm{Var}(S)$$

$\sqrt {n-1} S/\sigma$ follows chi distribution with $n-1$ degree of freedom. Its variance is $\frac {2[\Gamma(\frac {n-1}2)[\Gamma(1+ \frac {n-1}2)-[\Gamma(\frac {n}2)]}{\Gamma(\frac {n-1}2) } = V$. So the variance of $S$ is $\frac {\sigma^2}{n-1}V$.

So $$\mathrm{Var}(\hat \tau) = \frac {\sigma^2}n + (\Phi^{-1}(0.95))^2\frac {\sigma^2}{n-1}V$$

The square root of variance is the standard error.

Comment: How do you know that the asymptotic normal distribution has this variance for the MLE?  Shouldn't we use the inverse of the Fisher information matrix to estimate the variance instead?

Comment: eqn 9 on http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChiDistribution.html

Comment: If you doubt about why S has relation with chi distribution, you can find the answer at the beginning of the linked article. For a statistics, if we have its exact variance, we should not use the Fisher information. Of cause, maybe they are the same.

Comment: OK - I did not think about getting an exact distribution of S.  Thanks for the solution, @user158565.